# How to copy IIS configuration from a server to another?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, configuration

I have an already configured IIS on a Windows Server 2008 SP2.

I would like to replicate the same configuration on a brand new IIS installed on another 2008 SP2 server. Of course the hostname and IP will change, but the other machine configurations are the same.

How do I copy the configuration from the first server to the new server?

Answer (score 1):

Most configuration settings for IIS 7+ are in one file:

`%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

You can try just copying this file from one server to another. Make a backup of the target file first.

Certain settings in this file are machine specific:

- The sessionKey values under configProtectedData,
- When using Client Certificates, passwords under security authentication

If you have made changes to the machine.config and global web.config files, you may need to apply them to your new server as well.

The few IIS settings still in the registry are usually only-non-default if you changed them
yourself in the registry. If you haven't, you can ignore them.
.....

Comment: Typo in 'systemroot' -> I cannot fix it myself

Answer (score 1):

If you have application pool, password are encrypted using per machine key.
I blogged about it [here](http://www.lotp.fr/2012/10/internet-information-services-iis-manager-bad-data-exception-from-hresult-0x80090005/?lang=en)

Supported way:
Export configuration:

```
aspnet_regiis -px "iisConfigurationKey" "C:\iisConfigurationKey.xml" -pri 
aspnet_regiis -px "iisWasKey" "c:\iisWasKey.xml" –pri
```

Import on target:

```
aspnet_regiis -pi "iisConfigurationKey" "C:\iisConfigurationKey.xml" 
aspnet_regiis -pi "iisWasKey" "C:\iisWasKey.xml"
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I get "The RSA key container was not found".